# NodeJS: Why is this code throwing a warning?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have the following code, it works but it still throws the warning.
I'm running in Node v12.

```
(node:15985) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Here is the source code for the loop, thanks:

```
const links = await knex('links').where('active', true);
const links = await knex('links').where('active', true).catch((e) => console.log(e)) // does not work neither

for (let index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
  const element = links[index];
  console.log('Running with', index, element.uri);

  (async () => {
    try {
      const { statusCode } = await got({
        url: `${element.protocol}://${element.uri}:${element.port}`,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 5000
      })

      const check = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
      }

      await knex('checks').insert(check);
    } catch (error) {
      const check = {
        status: 'error',
      }

      await knex('checks').insert(check);
    }
  })().catch(() => {});
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it's the first `await knex` as there's no `catch` there.

Comment: I replaced with : await knex('monitors').where('active', true).catch((e) => console.log(e)), but Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 promises without a catch block:

- As pointed by @Phix in the comment, one on the first line:

  ```
  // On the first line
  await knex('links').where('active', true)
  ```
- In the catch block at the end of the code:

  `await knex('checks').insert(check);`

Comment: commenting the `await knex('checks').insert(check);` and doing `const links = await knex('links').where('active', true).catch((e) => console.log(e))` still raises the error

Comment: It will definitely help but maybe promises are used outside of the code you shared. Maybe you'll need to share a bigger part of the code that raises the error

Answer (score 0):

I made some change to the original code according to my understanding. I also suspect `await knex('checks').insert(check);` is the issue for the unhandled promise. So I added a try & catch to handle it. The `finally` is not required. I just want to make the flow a bit clear. I hope it solve the issue, at least provide some ideas.

```js
// assign the async salad to a const to make the flow a bit more clear
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    let check;
    const { statusCode } = await got({
      url: `${element.protocol}://${element.uri}:${element.port}`,
      method: 'GET',
      timeout: 5000
    })
    check = {
      statusCode: statusCode,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    check = {
      status: 'error',
    }
  } finally {
    // use a try catch to handle the potential async call
    try {
      await knex('checks').insert(check);
    } catch {
      throw new Error('Error')
    }

  }
};

// if await knex('checks').insert(check) fails, we can catch the error it throws 
try {
  fetchData()
} catch (erroe) {
  console.log(error);
}
```